# Unable to get the same results with 2 pieces of somewhat similar XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, undefined

Hope you are able to help or just help me understand why I have 2 almost similar codeblocks where one does not do what I expect.

I am trying to make some API calls where I populate a variable with the data that is pulled from the API call. In the first there is no problem at all, but the second I can't populate the variable. 
I have tried googling the problem and it seems to be because of the asynchronous nature of XmlHttprequests. But again, I do not get why one solutions works and another don't.

***The solution that work:***

```js
// Get JSON and convert it to an object
var obj;
const Http = new XMLHttpRequest();
const url = "https://type.fit/api/quotes";

Http.open("GET", url);
Http.send();

Http.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    obj = JSON.parse(Http.responseText);
  }
};
```

In this solution I am able to get the data and populate the variable obj and use it globally.

link to the solution: https://codepen.io/Kfriis/pen/QWjGZmx

***The solution that don't work:***

```js
//function that takes a currency in capital letters and returns 
  var rates;
  var currency = 'gbp';
  const currencyString = currency.toUpperCase();
  const API = "api.frankfurter.app"
  const URL = `https://${API}/latest?amount=1&from=${currencyString}&to=DKK`
  
  const http = new XMLHttpRequest();
  
  http.open("GET", URL);
  http.send();
  
  http.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        rates = JSON.parse(http.responseText);
        
      }
  };
  console.log(rates)
```

This do, for some reason, not work. I do not get why the rates variable do not get populated since the request is basically the same for the first code snippet. 
I have come down to an idea of it being because the data sent from the 2 API endpoints may be different in some way. Because if it was only because of the asynchronous requests, both code snippets should return undefined.

Link https://codepen.io/Kfriis/pen/VwvpKmd

I do hope someone is able to shine some light on this. 
I must be doing something wrong in the second snippet, because I can console.log() from inside the onreadystatechange but not outside it. Which led me to believe for a long time that it was a scoping issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does work. However, you're logging `console.log(rates)` outside the `http.onreadystatechange`-function which means you're logging the rates before you get the response. If you change the code block

```
 http.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        rates = JSON.parse(http.responseText);

      }
  };
  console.log(rates)
```

to

```
 http.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        rates = JSON.parse(http.responseText);
        console.log(rates)
      }
  };
```

it should work.

Here's a working example code if you wanna add the code to a function.

```
// Function that takes a currency in capital letters and returns 
function getCurrencyRates(currency, cb) {
  const currencyString = currency.toUpperCase();
  const API = "api.frankfurter.app"
  const URL = `https://${API}/latest?amount=1&from=${currencyString}&to=DKK`

  const http = new XMLHttpRequest();

  http.open("GET", URL);
  http.send();

  http.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            cb(JSON.parse(http.responseText));        
        }
  };
}

// Call the function and pass "gbp" as currency.
// Rates will be logged in response.
getCurrencyRates('gbp', function(response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

Comment: Hi Jonathan, 
I have gotten so far, but what I see as a weird difference in both code snippets is that in both I have a globally declared variable. 

In the first I am able to access this variable inside the http.onreadystatechange and populate within this function and use the data outside og http.onreadystatechang. 

But in the second I am not able to this. Is it because I am relying on console.log()? 
Because I see that in the first solution I am using the variable in a new function instead of just logging the variable and then I can access the variables data.

Comment: Both functions works exactly the same. The thing is, javascript won't wait for your functions to finish before continuing with your code. The HTTP-request will just initiate and start loading, let's say it takes 30 ms. While it does that, your code will continue and run the console.log within micro seconds. So when your console.log is triggered, the global variable `rates` haven't got its value assigned yet. That's why you will be able to call the variable later in the code, because then it would've got its value assigned from the response.